# issue with queue priority on RabbitMqBundle

Tags: symfony, rabbitmq

I am trying to setup a priority queue. Without priority, it is working just fine but I need to prioritize messages.

I am using RabbitMqBundle 1.14 and rabbitmq-supervisor-bundle 3.1 with RabbitMQ 3.5.7 (Erlang 18.3)

Here is the config.yml :

```
old_sound_rabbit_mq:
    connections:
        default:
            host:     '127.0.0.1'
            port:     5672
            user:     'xxx'
            password: 'xxx'
            vhost:    '/'
            lazy:     false
            connection_timeout: 3
            read_write_timeout: 3

            # requires php-amqplib v2.4.1+ and PHP5.4+
            keepalive: false

            # requires php-amqplib v2.4.1+
            heartbeat: 0

            #requires php_sockets.dll
            use_socket: true # default false
    producers:
        global:
            connection:       default
            exchange_options: {name: 'global', type: direct}
            queue_options:
                name: global
    consumers:
        global:
            connection:       default
            exchange_options: {name: 'global', type: direct}
            queue_options:    {name: 'global', arguments: {'x-max-priority': ['I', 10]} }
            callback:         rabbitmq_simu_service
```

And the message sent to queue :

```
$msg = array();
$msg['id'] = $id;
$msg['action'] = 'simu';
$additionalProperties = ['priority' => 4] ;  
$routing_key = '';
$this->container->get('old_sound_rabbit_mq.global_producer')->publish(serialize($msg), $routing_key , $additionalProperties);
```

I get the following error when sending the message :

PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-max-priority' for queue 'global' in vhost '/': received none but current is the value '10' of type 'signedint'

I also tried in the config.yml :

```
            queue_options:    {name: 'global', arguments: {'x-max-priority': 10} }
```

In this case, I got no error but messages are not consumed.

Does anyone know how to send priority message ?

Comment: Make sure that your queue in RabbitMQ is created with support for priorities. You may need to delete and re-create queue e.g. in a case if you have added priority requirement to configuration after creating actual queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-max-priority' for queue 'global' in vhost '/': received none but current is the value '10' of type 'signedint'

That message means that you have already created the `global` queue with a max priority of `10`, but something else is trying to declare it with no priority. You must review your code for both your producer *and* consumer to ensure that if they declare this priority queue they use exactly the same `x-max-priority` argument.

Answer (score 2):

The message you have received is the error message for what happens when you try to create a queue, but the queue already exists with different parameters. You must delete the queue first, then try running your program.